# PHP array path from values

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have this array

```
$ar=array(
'cat','dog','turtle','eagle'
);
```

I want to generate another array with this result

```
$arFinal=array(
[cat,dog,turtle,eagle],
[cat,dog,turtle],
[cat,dog],
[cat],
[dog,turtle,eagle],
[dog,turtle],
[dog],
[turtle,eagle],
[turtle],
[eagle],
);
```

Comment: And what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Write a loop with counters and use `array_slice( $ar, $start, $length )`. Your loop should generate the numbers (start - length): 0-4 , 0-3, 0-2, 0-1, 1-3, 1-2, 1-1, 2-2, 2-1, 3-1

Answer (score 0):

Top of the mornin’ to you,
my solution (from the comments on your question):

```
<?php
    $array = array('cat','dog','turtle','eagle');

    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        for($l = $i; $l < count($array); $l++){
            $result[] = array_slice($array, $i, count($array)-$l);
        }
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
    array(4) { [0]=>  "cat" [1]=>  "dog" [2]=>  "turtle" [3]=>  "eagle" }
    array(3) { [0]=>  "cat" [1]=>  "dog" [2]=>  "turtle" }
    array(2) { [0]=>  "cat" [1]=>  "dog" }
    array(1) { [0]=>  "cat" }
    array(3) { [0]=>  "dog" [1]=>  "turtle" [2]=>  "eagle" }
    array(2) { [0]=>  "dog" [1]=>  "turtle" }
    array(1) { [0]=>  "dog" }
    array(2) { [0]=>  "turtle" [1]=>  "eagle" }
    array(1) { [0]=>  "turtle" }
    array(1) { [0]=>  "eagle" } 
}
```

Sincerely,
Sam.